# Collision problem with three expanding circles

Tags: algebra-precalculus, numerical-methods

Suppose you drop 3 droplets in a quiet lake at different locations and at slightly different times. Find the location and time where the three resulting circular wave fronts meet for the first time.

One way of formulating this problem into math could be:

Suppose you have three distinct points in $A, B, C \in \mathbb{R}^2$ not on a line and three initial radii $r_{A}, r_{B}, r_{C} \in \mathbb{R}_+$. Let $(x, y, t) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}_+$. Consider the follow 3 (circle) equations

$$ (A_x - x)^2 + (A_y - y)^2 = (r_A + t)^2 $$
$$ (B_x - x)^2 + (B_y - y)^2 = (r_B + t)^2 $$
$$ (C_x - x)^2 + (C_y - y)^2 = (r_C + t)^2 $$

I want find the triple $(x, y, t)$ satisfying all three equations and with $t$ being the least number possible (minimal).

I am looking for an exact solution or an appropriate numerical algorithm with fast computation time.

Thank you.

Ps. assume $\max(r_A, r_B, r_C) < \min(|AB|, |BC|, |AC|)$ where e.g. $|AB|$ is the euclidean distance between points $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Subtracting any of the equations from the other two should give you linear equations which can express $(x,y)$ in terms of $t$. Substitute that in any one of the above equations above to solve for $t$, provided it exists. Doesn't seem too difficult (except being cumbersome) to try, in case you run into issues, post the specifics.

Comment: You're looking for the circumcentre of the triangle ABC, the intersection of the perpendicular bisectors of the triangle's edges.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle

Comment: @JaapScherphuis It would be that if the $r$'s were all the same.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Ah, I overlooked that issue. That complicates things.

Comment: @JacobHarder Just a side comment: if the droplets fall at times $t = 0$, $t=t_B$ and $t=t_C$ the RH Sides become $t^2$, $(t-t_B)^2$ and $(t-t_C)^2$. Of course, any admissible solution would satisfy $t\ge t_C$.

Comment: @JacobHarder If the droplets are dropped at very close locations, the fronts may never meet (at least in an infinite lake, lol).

Comment: @Macavity yes, you are correct. I somehow missed this - thanks.

Comment: @PierreCarre I think my last condition (in the ps.) takes care of your case with the fronts never meeting